# Best practices for fetching and displaying many amount of data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

As the title said, I'm implementing a webpage which display many chart and table with .net

> (note: i dont have prior experience with .net, but i do have experience with other language. so its not that hard for me to do the implementation. The thing is I want to know whether what I'm doing is "correct" or not)

So, this page suppose to display bunch of chart and table which have different set of data. Currently I'm implementing it with MVC where the controller fetch all the data at once, and then return the view with an object that saving all those data.

it goes something like this:

**Model:**

```
public class AViewModel
{
    Public List<ClassofData1> DataForTable1 { get; set; }
    Public List<ClassofData2> DataForTable2 { get; set; }
    Public List<ClassofData3> DataForChart1 { get; set; }
    Public List<ClassofData4> DataForChart2 { get; set; }
    ... //repeat for dozen of time :)
}
```

**controller:**

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AViewModel DataforView = mew AViewModel();

        DataforView.DataForTable1 = Fetch1(); //im oversimplifying here, but it basically goes like this
        DataforView.DataForTable2 = Fetch2();
        DataforView.DataForChart1 = Fetch3();
        DataforView.DataForChart2 = Fetch4();
        ... //repeat for another dozen of time :)

        return View("Index", DataforView);
    }
}
```

And then display everything on a HTML page.

Is it okay to implement it like that? loading all those data into a single viewmodel and "dump" it all on the HTML page.

Or should i make bunch of API which the HTML page call one by one to fetch those data, instead of loading everything at once in the index controller just like i did?

Comment: The View should not fetch data, only present the data from the ViewModel.

Comment: So, does that mean what im doing is alright? @SirRufo

Answer (score 0):

You need A piginating. Here is an example https://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/

In short, you should execute Sorted requests (By default by ID as example).

Your action should see like this:

```
ActionResult Search(string query, int startIndex, int pageSize) {...}
```

Your response shoud be like this:

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    int PageCount { get; }
    int TotalItemCount { get; }
    int PageIndex { get; }
    int PageNumber { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
    bool HasNextPage { get; }
    bool IsFirstPage { get; }
    bool IsLastPage { get; }
}
```

So, by PageNumber and PageSize you can calculate start and end index of elements. To select like this please use

```
var page = source.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which chart are you using? Can we bind it using a JSON array? if it is possible to bind it using JS then you should create different actions to fetch chart data. And bind chart from javascript [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) methods on document ready.

Comment: im using highchart.js, and yes that was what im thinking of, since im looking for the best pratices for doing this.